# terraform get index value from the list of maps

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to feed each value of the `vault_field` for aws secret manager secret_string with this code.

`variables.tf`

```
variable "aws_secrets" {
  type = list(
    object({
      aws_secret_id = string,
      vault_path    = string,
      vault_field   = string,
    })
  )
  default = []
}
```

`main.tf`

```
data "vault_generic_secret" "aws_secrets" {
  for_each = { for idx, val in var.aws_secrets : idx => val }

  path = each.value.vault_path
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "aws_secrets" {
  for_each                = { for idx, val in var.aws_secrets : idx => val }
  name                    = "my-secrets"
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "aws_secrets" {
  for_each      = { for idx, val in var.aws_secrets : idx => val }
  secret_id     = aws_secretsmanager_secret.aws_secrets[each.key].id
  secret_string = jsonencode(data.vault_generic_secret.aws_secrets[2])
}
```

however I get this error

```
Error: Invalid index

76:   secret_string = jsonencode(data.vault_generic_secret.aws_secrets[2])
├────────────────
│ data.vault_generic_secret.aws_secrets is object with 1 attribute "0"

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to hardcode an index of the secret. You also need to actually refer to `secret_string` attribute:

```
secret_string = jsonencode(data.vault_generic_secret.aws_secrets[each.key].   data_json)
```

or

```
secret_string = jsonencode(data.vault_generic_secret.aws_secrets[each.key].   data)
```

Comment: Tried it, but get this error

`Error: Unsupported attribute \
data.vault_generic_secret.aws_secrets is object with 1 attribute "0" \
each.key is "0" \
This object does not have an attribute named "secret_string".`